# Adding an Option to a Select Element with javascript using the Prototype library

Tags: javascript, select, prototypejs

I want a to add an option dynamically to a Select element using Prototype.

There seems to be a lot of different ways to do it out there, all to do with options.add etc... Not seen much in the way of cross-browser ways.

Want it to be as lightweight as possible.

This is what I have got so far. It's just the appending the options that I'm stuck on:

```
var oNewOption = new Element('option').value=vItem;
oNewOption.text=vItem;
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select.insert(new Element('option', {value: myValue}).update(myLabel));
```

*insert* appends to the content of the *select* object, *update* updates the content of the new option object.

Not really better than the classic way, though.

Comment: This worked as per what i wanted to do, although for some reason .insert() was not returning the element to be updated so: insert(option).update(myLabel) didn't work. So changed it to: option.update(myLabel);select.insert(option);

Work's a treat.

Comment: If you look closely, the _update_ is on the object returned by _new_, not the one returned by _insert_.

Answer (score 26):

No need for Prototype, it'll be just as easy with the following time-honoured method that works in every major desktop browser since the mid-1990s:

```
// Assuming a select element stored in a variable called 'select'
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("Option text", "optionValue");
```

Comment: Thank you but was looking to use prototype as the rest of the code is using prototype!

Will keep this in mind in future when using prototype is not a requirement!

Comment: Prototype is just a library. There's no need to use it for everything, and nothing stopping you from mixing regular DOM methods in with your Prototype code.

Comment: +1. `select.options.add(new Option('foo','bar'))` is also supported pretty well.

Comment: you should not use the "Option constructor", because it is not W3C standard. you should use "document.createElement('option')" as proved in this [article](http://0x657573.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/where-is-new-option-defined/)

Comment: @ESt3b4n: Not true. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-option

Comment: Thanks @Tim Down. I just didn't look at HTML5 because it's just a "future" version ([HTML-Specs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Specifications)). Browsers always allowed the use of the constructor Option (since Netscape) even without the/a standard specification ([old-document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6408-10/option.htm)). I think W3c was just pushed to add it for the future specification HTML5, let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Another question: Isn't suppose that the DOM defines the way in which HTML document objects are exposed to javascript?? so why the [constructor Option documentation](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-option) you gives, appears in a W3C-HTML document and not in a W3C-DOM document?

Comment: @ESt3b4n: Good question. The line between what goes into the DOM spec and what goes into the HTML spec seems quite blurry and I don't have a good answer. With regard to your previous comment, I don't think the `Option` constructor was specified anywhere prior to HTML5 but one of the main goals of HTML5 was to specify exactly this sort of thing (widely implemented, non-standard APIs), and while HTML5 is not exactly finished, all browser vendors are committed to implementing it. Therefore, old APIs that are standardized in HTML5 are safe to use for the foreseeable future.